# I'm trying to find the prime numbers within a range. I initialised the flag at the beginning of code. Why does it need to be initialised within loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops, primes, reset

This does not give me the correct output whereas putting flag=0 within the for loop, provides perfect output. Why is that so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int upper, lower,flag=0, i, j;
    
    printf("Enter the range of nos. ");
    scanf("%d %d",&lower,&upper);
    printf("The prime nos. are ");
    for(i=lower;i<=upper;i=i+1)
    {
        for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
        {
            if((i%j)==0)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(flag==0){
            printf("%d ",i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once `flag` becomes `1`, it will never become `0` again, and, I believe, you want to reset it for each prime candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop is setting the flag when it sees that the candidate number is not prime.  So when the inner loop exits, if the flag is not set then it knows the number is prime.

If you don't reset `flag` to 0 before the inner loop starts, a prior iteration of the inner loop may have set it to 1.  If that's the case, `flag` will remain 1 and no numbers after the first non-prime will be seen as prime.

Answer (score 0):

If you will not reset the flag in the outer loop then the previous value of the flag will be used for a next number. So if the previous number is not a prime number then for all subsequent numbers the flag will be equal tp 1 independent on whether a subsequent number is a prime number.

But even if you will reset the flag in the outer loop as it is required nevertheless your program is incorrect. If to use the range when `lower` is equal to `0` and `upper` is equal to `1` then your program will print numbers `0` and `1` as prime numbers though they are not prime numbers.

Also there is no sense to use the signed integer type `int` for values of the range. The user can enter negative numbers.

```
I would write the program the following way as it is shown below.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int lower = 0, upper = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter a range of non-negative numbers (lower and when upper: " );
    
    scanf( "%u%u", &lower, &upper );
    
    if ( upper < lower )
    {
        unsigned int tmp = upper;
        upper = lower;
        lower = tmp;
    }
    
    printf( "Prime numbers in the range [%u, %u]: ", lower, upper );
    
    for ( unsigned int i = lower; i <= upper; ++i )
    {
        int prime = i % 2 == 0 ? i == 2 : i != 1;
        
        for ( unsigned int j = 3; prime && j <= i / j; j += 2 )
        {
            prime = i % j != 0;
        }
        
        if ( prime ) printf( "%u ", i );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a range of non-negative numbers (lower and when upper: 0 100
Prime numbers in the range [0, 100]: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```